# button arrows not working and wrong number of elements showing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been cobbling something together from different examples that I have seen online  I would like to know why is it not just showing 1 button per page and instead showing them all and decreasing the numbers of visible buttons for each right click by one. And yet when you click the left arrow it shows a blank screen.

Also if you click the right arrow after clicking the left arrow you will be stuck on a page with only one button, and the left still just shows a blank screen.

I am trying to have only one button on screen at a time and be able to switch between the different buttons via the right and left arrows. this is for an idle mine game.

```css
.hide {

  display: none;

}

.step-box {

  width: 640px;

  height: 150px;

  border: 1px solid;

  position: relative;

}

.names-content {

  padding: 10px

}

ul {

  list-style: none;

}

li {

  float: center;

  margin: 5px;

  background: #ABA38F;

  color: #fff;

  padding: 5px;

}

li span {

  width: 150px;

  text-align: left;

}

.arrows {

  position: absolute;

  top: 70px;

  cursor: pointer;

}

.arrow-left {

  left: 10px;

}

.arrow-right {

  right: 10px;

}

.arrows span {

  width: 30px;

  height: 30px;

  border-radius: 30px;

  background: #BABABA;

  color: #fff;

  clear: both;

  display: block;

  text-align: center;

  font-size: 20px;

  line-height: 30px;

}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test2.css" />
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="step-box">


    <div class="names-content">
      <ul id="mines">
        <li>test1</li>
        <li class="hide">test2</li>
        <li class="hide">test3</li>
        <li class="hide">test4</li>
        <li class="hide">test5</li>
        <li class="hide">test6</li>
        <li class="hide">test7</li>
        <li class="hide">test8</li>
        <li class="hide">test9</li>
        <li class="hide">test0</li>
        <li class="hide">test01</li>



      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="arrows arrow-right"> <span><i> > </i></span>
    </div>
    <div class="arrows arrow-left"> <span><i> < </i></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    var arrowRightCount = 0;
    var arrowLeftCount = 0;

    $(document).ready(function() {

      //RIGHT ARROW
      $(".step-box .arrow-right").click(function(e) {
        console.log("right arrow clicked");
        var lnt = $("#mines > li").length;
        if (lnt > 1) {
          arrowRightCount = arrowRightCount + 1;
          arrowLeftCount = arrowLeftCount - 1;

          if (arrowRightCount > lnt) {
            arrowRightCount = lnt;
          }

          for (var i = 0; i < arrowRightCount; i++) {
            $("#mines > li:eq(" + i + ")").addClass('hide');
          }

          var jlimit = arrowRightCount + 1;
          if (jlimit > lnt) {
            jlimit = lnt;
          }

          for (var j = arrowRightCount; j < jlimit; j++) {
            $("#mines > li:eq(" + i + ")").removeClass('hide');
          }


        }

      });


      //LEFT ARROW
      $(".step-box .arrow-left").click(function(e) {
        console.log("left arrow clicked");
        var lnt = $("#mines > li").length;
        if (lnt > 1) {
          arrowLeftCount = arrowLeftCount + 1;
          arrowRightCount = arrowRightCount - 1;

          if (arrowLeftCount > lnt) {
            arrowLeftCount = lnt;
          }

          for (var i = 0; i < arrowLeftCount; i++) {
            $("#mines > li:eq(" + i + ")").addClass('hide');
          }

          var jlimit = arrowLeftCount + 1;
          if (jlimit > lnt) {
            jlimit = lnt;
          }

          for (var j = arrowLeftCount; j < jlimit; j++) {
            $("#mines > li:eq(" + i + ")").removeClass('hide');
          }


        }

      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?  And what does "not working" mean?

Comment: @Becuzz I have revamped this question to more accurately state what I need help with

Comment: Do you mean you want to make it work like it's in example jsfiddle link?

Comment: @Nimesh Sort of. It should be able to click right and left and only show one button per "slide"  like in the example. Really i guess what i am looking for is why my code isnt working how it should

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope that you are able to understand what your code is doing...
From what I understood, the jquery part is adding the class **hide** to the list items to hide and removing it from the list items to be displayed.

1] All the buttons are being displayed as initially none of the items have the class **hide** set to them, to do this either apply the attribute `class="hide"` to all the list items in html or create a function in JavaScript and run it on pageload.

2] For the inconsistent behavior of left & right buttons, check the jquery part, those are not identical in operations. Make the left one as right one and see the difference.

**For right button**:

```
arrowRightCount = arrowRightCount + 3;
arrowLeftCount = arrowLeftCount - 3;
```

**For left button**:

```
arrowLeftCount = arrowLeftCount - 3;
arrowRightCount = arrowRightCount - 3;
```

3] if you want to display only 1 button, why are you using 3 for everything in jquery, make it to 1 and it should display only 1 button

**Tip:** Use different names for buttons to see actually which button is being displayed and in what order.

**Update:** Even I'm not much familiar with jquery but this is very minimal.
Check this updated jquery, since all the list items are already hidden we don't need to apply the add/remove class action for all the items, so modified it to apply only on the items being modified i.e. prev/next based on counter (cntr) to identify the current position.
Check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1aany4xb/4/) for output

```
var mincount = 0; 
var maxcount = 10;
var cntr = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {

  //RIGHT ARROW
  $(".step-box .arrow-right").click(function(e) {
    if(cntr >= mincount && cntr < maxcount){
      $("#mines > li:eq(" + cntr + ")").addClass('hide');
      cntr = cntr + 1;
      $("#mines > li:eq(" + cntr + ")").removeClass('hide');
    }
  });

  //LEFT ARROW
  $(".step-box .arrow-left").click(function(e) {
    if(cntr > mincount && cntr <= maxcount){
      $("#mines > li:eq(" + cntr + ")").addClass('hide');
      cntr = cntr - 1;
      $("#mines > li:eq(" + cntr + ")").removeClass('hide');
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: I have updated the code in the main question and it is showing the propper number of buttons until you hit the left click arrow then it shows two. I am not well versed in jquery but i believe it has something to do with this:
  `if(arrowLeftCount > lnt){
        arrowLeftCount = lnt;`

in the left arrow section if you change `>` to `<` it won't work but as it is it shows 2 buttons.

Comment: OHHHH ok, i see whats going on right now. Thanks alot @Nimesh